# TortoiseHg won't run in 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I upgraded last week to 13.04 (via fresh install) and have separately attempted to install tortoiseHg using Software Center and command line, both apparently successful.  The problem is when I try to launch the application, nothing happens. I have also tried to launch from commandline using **thg**, but again without success. Is it likely that I have missed a dependency, or is there a problem with Tortoise in 13.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written by Attila Fulop, the package in 13.04 is broken. To work around the problem, type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will download and install a version properly working in 13.04. hth

Answer (score 4):

It's known to not work with 13.04, so it's not your fault.

There's a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tortoisehg/+bug/1152912) on launchpad, and Kostya Vasilyev has recommended the following workaround:

> I've been running TortoiseHG and Mercurial from these PPAs, they need to be installed together (thg requires a certain range of hg verisons)...
>
> https://launchpad.net/~tortoisehg-ppa/+archive/stable-snapshots
>
> https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/stable-snapshots
>
> There are no "raring" versions, but the ones for "quantal" have been working just fine

So you can use this until the bundled version is fixed.